# why does dc amperage change if I install the power supply up-side down

Tags: power-supply

I build electrical control panels. I received a set of prints with a note to install the 24vdc power supplies in the upright position, because in the inverted position, the power supplies would drop from 10A output to 6A and the life span of the units would be reduced. Can anyone explain this to me? In 25 years, I've never seen this note before.

Comment: din panel? air flow would be my guess

Comment: I agree with @PlasmaHH , my guess would be improper airflow when mounted upside-down, meaning components would cook at lower currents than usual and would degrade faster

Comment: You should include a link to the datasheet of those supplies. If these do not have a fan then I also agree with PlasmaHH: temperature reasons.

Answer (score 4):

Why must current drop if heat rises? This has to do with Arrhenius Effect of with MTBF reducing 50% for each 10'C junction rise in semiconductors. Orientation of convection flow on the hottest parts could have this effect to optimize the chimney effect in one direction.  Convection Air flow has a significant effect the thermal resistance in deg C/ Watt. In this case 40% is significant.

Comment: That and all the electrons fall out of the capacitors....